# Apache <RequireAny> only when HTTPS

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-auth

I'd like to use Basic Auth only when HTTPS is used. Having a .htaccess like this the user must enter password twice

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteOptions Inherit

# Rewrite to HTTPS (except for let's encrypt)
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/.*$
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

<RequireAny>
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Top Secret"
    AuthUserFile /is/htdocs/***/.htpasswd
    Require valid-user
</RequireAny>
```

Using this file:

- http://mysite.domain is called
- Authentication for 'http://mysite.domain' is requested (NoSSL)
- Redirect to https://mysite.domain is done
- Authentication for 'https://mysite.domain' is requested (SSL)

How can I avoid the authentication for 'http://mysite.domain' here?

Answer (score 0):

Found it, using REQUEST_SCHEME.

```
<If "%{REQUEST_SCHEME} == 'https'">
    <RequireAny>
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Top Secret"
        AuthUserFile /is/htdocs/***/.htpasswd
        Require valid-user
    </RequireAny>
</If>
```